# Does anyone know a DimScreen (brightness) for ubuntu?

Tags: brightness

does anyone know if there is an app like DimScreen for ubuntu? Dimscreen reduce the brightness of monitor using a gray filter. There are similar app also on Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:
http://joeltong.org/blog/?p=166
If you want to change lcd brightness:
There is also xbacklight (see software center) and this script http://pastebin.com/HzzHrS2g